# GXT - RequestFactory integration with Paging Grid

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, requestfactory

I am having difficulties understanding how my ***Service*** class should be written in order to implement GXT pagination with `RequestFactory`

I followed the example provided in the [Demo site](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3arequestfactorygrid), as well as the [javadoc example](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ui/widgets/grid/loading/GridLoadingRequestFactory.html) given in the Sencha website, but failed to completely understand both.

To start with let us say that my *Service* is returning `List<Data>` (`Data` is a server POJO) which needs to be loaded in a paginated fashion.

Here is my Service class which has exposed a pagination method

```
class BackendService {

   public List<Data> getData(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
        int f = pageNumber * pageSize;
        int l = f + pageSize;
        if(f > 0 && l < datas.size()) {
            return  datas.subList(f, l);
        }
        return null;
   }
}
```

The `RequestFactory` looks like this

```
    @Service(value=BackendService.class, locator=BackendServiceLocator.class)
    interface BackendRequestContext extends RequestContext {

       Request<List<DataProxy>> getData(int pageNumber, int pageSize);

    }

    BackendRequestContext context();
}
```

The paging `Grid` is expecting a `DataProxy` implementation as follows

```
DataProxy<PagingLoadConfig, PagingLoadResult<com.emc.test.client.model.DataProxy>> proxy = new RequestFactoryProxy<PagingLoadConfig, PagingLoadResult<com.emc.test.client.model.DataProxy>>() {

            @Override
            public void load(PagingLoadConfig loadConfig, Receiver<? super PagingLoadResult<com.emc.test.client.model.DataProxy>> receiver) {
                int pageNum = loadConfig.getOffset();
                int pageSize = loadConfig.getLimit();
                Request<List<com.emc.test.client.model.DataProxy>> request = backendRequestFactory.context().getData(pageNum, pageSize);
                request.fire(receiver);
            }

};
```

In the above `load` method, this line is giving compilation error

```
request.fire(receiver);
```

because `Receiver` is expected to be

```
Receiver<? super PagingLoadResult<com.emc.test.client.model.DataProxy>>
```

Can anyone please help me regarding

- how should I implement the service method?
- Should i return `PagingLoadResult` instead of `List` from service itself? If yes how?

Thank you for your time on this thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more dto-proxy pair which extend PagingLoadResultBean/PagingLoadResult.

1) In backend part you have create the following dto:

```
public class YourCustomPagingLoadResultBean extends PagingLoadResultBean<Data> {

  protected YourCustomPagingLoadResultBean () {
  }

  public YourCustomPagingLoadResultBean (List<Data> list, int totalLength, int offset) {
    super(list, totalLength, offset);
  }
}
```

2) Create proxy for this dto:

```
@ProxyFor(YourCustomPagingLoadResultBean.class)
public interface YourCustomPagingLoadResultProxy extends ValueProxy, PagingLoadResult<DataProxy> {
  @Override
  List<DataProxy> getData();
}
```

3) Change you service to return paging bean:

```
public YourCustomPagingLoadResultBean getData(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {
  ...
  return new YourCustomPagingLoadResultBean(list, totalLength, offset);
}
```

4) Request also changes to:

```
Request<YourCustomPagingLoadResultProxy> getData(int pageNumber, int pageSize);
```

The `DataProxy` you are using looks correct, your paging grid will work after these 4 steps.

Comment: Awesome!.. thank you for clearing that out.. I often face difficulties understanding complex contracts expected to be implemented by Sencha. Can you also point me out to the documents which are available online regarding the same?

Comment: I wish there were any :(
GXT examples page is your best friend. If something is missing there, it was surely discussed on official forum or here, on stackoverflow.
[Official blog](http://www.sencha.com/blog/category/sencha-gxt) also has several explanatory articles and is a good place to start from.